# How to List my application in Application sync settings config screen on android 1.5?

Tags: android

How do I list my app in Data Synchronization -> Application sync settings on android 1.5?

Gmail, Calendar and contacs are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature needs Android 2.0.

If you need to be 1.5 compatible what you can do is the following:

a) Compile against Android 2.1
b) Fix the `AndroidManifest` using:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
```

c) Check the using reflection section in [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html).

Basically you first ask if the feature exist, if it does you use if not show some kind of msg.

Comment: But Gmail shows in Application sync settings event in Adroid 1.5, there must be a way to do so with any app. Is Google using a hidden/locked API for that?

Comment: Kalecser: The api was released for android 2.0.

Comment: I understand that, but there are applications in android 1.5 that use that 'feature', if the API was released for android 2.0 how did they use the feature in android 1.5?